# "On one of such days" Vs "On one such day"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which of the two is correct? Or are they both.

In which cases would one be preferred over the other?

**Edit 1: Context** 
I made other adjustments. Adjustments which included leaving my car at home parked. `On one of such days`, I see it from . . .

Comment: Lacking context, I would think the second is the correct one, but I could construct a sentence with the first version too

Comment: They're both "valid", but [on one such day](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22on+one+such+day%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is far more common than [on one of such days](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22on+one+of+such+days%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (by about 15:1 in Google Books there). I'm not sure any specific context favours the latter.

Comment: I'm not convinced that "on one of such days" is a valid alternative for "on one such day" - a Google search for {"on one of such days" - "on one of such days as"} shows an insignificant number of hits.

Comment: Without knowing the context, I would suggest "one of *those* days", as in "It's been one of those days".

Comment: @mplungjan: context now added, hopefully it now clearer.

Comment: _On such days I can see it from my bedroom window..._ if you want to describe more than one. _On one of those days, I forgot my key in the ignition_ if it is only one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*One of such* is not commonly used as a compound determiner with the meaning 'one of the type just specified'. This claim is supported by the results of Ngrams for "one such X,one of such X's" where X = opportunity, problem, day, task... . Care has to be taken with a raw Google search to filter out false positives like 'one of such problems as tend to occur in this type of research' where the compound determiner is *one of* NOT *one of such*. A Google search for "on one of such days" - "on one of such days as" shows an insignificant number of hits.